# Trying to remove anchor text within brackets via jQuery / replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I've been searching through stackoverflow to find a solution to this but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to select anything inside of "( )" brackets in primary/parent links within a menu and remove them with `.replace()` but nothing seems to be happening.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/1rndwz3u/1/

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    jQuery(".menu-name-menu-category-menu ul.nav li > a").html().replace(/\(.*?\)/g,"");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-name-menu-category-menu">
    <ul class="menu nav">
        <li class="first expanded dropdown active-trail">
            <a title="Heavy Equipment Rentals (0)" href="#">Heavy Equipment Rentals (0)<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="accordion-body">
                <li><a title="Excavator Rentals (2)" href="#">Excavator Rentals (2)</a></li>
                <li><a title="Mini Excavator Rentals (6)" href="#">Mini Excavator Rentals (6)</a></li>
                <li><a title="Skid Steer Rentals (9)" href="#">Skid Steer Rentals (9)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active-trail"><a title="Tool Rentals (1)" href="#">Tool Rentals (1)</a></li>
        <li class="last expanded dropdown active-trail">
            <a title="Construction Rentals (0)" href="#">Construction Rentals (0) <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="accordion-body">
                <li><a title="Gator, UTV &amp; ATV Rentals (2)" href="#">Gator, UTV &amp; ATV Rentals (2)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried using `.html()` and `.text()` but neither did anything, also tried grabbing just "Rentals" instead of a regex for the brackets and that didn't work either. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1rndwz3u/8/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    $( ".menu-name-menu-category-menu ul.nav li.expanded > a" ).each(function( index,elem ) {
          $(elem).html($(elem).html().replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ""));
    });

});
```

Comment: I was trying to only remove/replace it from the top level menu items, how would I alter this code to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: That's looking great! Unfortunately "Tool Rentals" is also a top level menu item but the (1) is showing there?

Comment: Give to the li .expanded class

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked a the Fiddle yet but

```
jQuery(".menu-name-menu-category-menu ul.nav li > a").html().replace(/\(.*?\)/g,"");
```

returns a string and must be set back into the HTML.

```
var HTML = jQuery(".menu-name-menu-category-menu ul.nav li > a").html().replace(/\(.*?\)/g,"");
jQuery(".menu-name-menu-category-menu ul.nav li > a").html( HTML );
```

Comment: I pasted that into the fiddle to test but it didn't work either unfortunately.

And to try and clarify what you said, the .replace() is creating a string and then you're adding it back into the HTML afterwards?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have not tested the regex that you need to this , so this may not be a complete answer. But I do know that `.replace()` creates a new string from the `.html()` string. It has to be saved into a variable then set back into the element `.html( HTML )`.

Answer (score 2):

You are editing the value but not doing anything with it. Try wrapping it with one more `html()` call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var target =  jQuery(".menu-name-menu-category-menu ul.nav li > a");
    target.html(target.html().replace(/\(.*?\)/g,""));
});
```

Comment: Tried this in the JSFiddle but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: in the fiddle, jQuery is not defined (check your developer console). Maybe try $ instead?

Comment: Here's a fork of the fiddle with $, also removed the regex and replaced with "Rentals" to ensure it wasn't the Regex: http://jsfiddle.net/rbhdwbfg/